# how find name window from .exe?

Tags: c++, winapi, window-handles

I have window Rules of Survival title: "Rules of Survival 1.120471.124472".

HWND window = FindWindow(NULL, "Rules of Survival 1.120471.124472");

how to find title name in rulesofsurvival.exe

pleas give me example

P.S. sorry for my bad English

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Don't you set the title in your application?

Comment: Why do you assume, that the window title were stored verbatim in the executable image? It could just as well be constructed at runtime. Since it apparently contains a version number, this is likely, too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to figure out what the window class of the target window is (using a tool like spy++) then use FindWindow/FindWindowEx with that class name.

Harder would be to enumerate all top level windows using GetDesktopWindow/GetWindow then use GetWindowThreadProcessId to get the thread and process ID that owns the window.

Comment: Use `EnumWindows()` to enumerate top-level windows

Comment: ... or use `EnumThreadWindows()`.